# Work done when you bring an bringing an object down from a height

Tags: forces, energy, work, potential-energy

I am going to explain this question through an example.

Suppose I lift an object I apply a force $mg $ then I apply additional force, that would be $ma $ so total force would be $m(g+a)$. My doubt is that the work done by a person in lifting a box by applying more force than the weight that should be $m(g+a) *h $ right?

I would love to know if my answer is right or if someone could kindly correct me

Answer (score 4):

That is correct. Also, since the gravitational PE increases by $mgh$ it is clear that the kinetic energy increases by $mah$

Answer (score 1):

Normally in lifting, you apply a momentary extra force to get the object moving, and then proceed at a constant speed.  As Dale points out, the extra work goes into kinetic energy.